# как реализовать цикл запросов на сервер в AcyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Хотелось бы сделать цикл в котором в doInBackground собиралась информация с сервера и уже в postExecute она добавлялась в форму. Потом опять опрос сервера и форма. Не понятно как грамотно зациклить acynktаsk, как понимаю это не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это будет неправильно. ошибка и все поедет.... используйте retrofit2 и RxJava, оператором zip вы сможете сделать не сколько запрос в один заход

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29918329/2667883

Время потраченное на изучение этой связки библиотек, оправдает ваши ожидание на все 100% вы получите бесценный опыт, нежели если потратите время на асинктак.